# What is the expiration time threshold below which LetsEncrypt certificates will auto-renew?

Tags: letsencrypt

I have a few domains on some server, all certified by LetsEncrypt certificates. The certificate is due to expire in 11 days, on July 9th.

However, when I try to renew using `/opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew`, I get this:

```
The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/what1.ever.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/what2.ever.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/what3.ever.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/what4.ever.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
```

It seems a bit odd that certificates can't be renewed 11 days before the expire, but it might be a matter of policy rather than a bug.

**What is the expiration time threshold below which LetsEncrypt certificates will auto-renew?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [certbot documentation](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#renewal):

> This will attempt to renew any
>   previously-obtained certificates
>   that expire in **less than 30 days**.

Comment: I just read the same, elsewhere (sorry, tab closed now): the automatic process starts polling after 60 days. That *should* mean your manual process will receive new certs within the other 30 days of the 90-day lifetime.